# issue of retrieving fcm token?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, token

```
problem of retrieving fcm token. iam working on sos alert web application using firebase cloud messaging. every this is good but iam not getting registration token.
```

const fcmToken = await getToken(messaging {vapidkey: 'VAPID_KEY'})

```
console.log(fcmToken)
```

FCM Token not being logged to the console.